# Switching from ReactDOM.render to createRoot makes simple jest test fail

Tags: javascript, reactjs, testing, jestjs, react-18

I just started studying "Mastering React Test-Driven Development" by Daniel Irvine, and I figured that it shouldn't be too hard to convert the examples to React 18. But I am running into trouble converting the very first test in the book using Jest.

The book doesn't use `create-react-app` or anything, but instead builds the React apps from scratch, so I'm having trouble finding relevant examples of how to convert the code.

When written as in the book, in React 17 style, the test passes. But if I replace `ReactDOM.render()` with `createRoot()`, the test fails.

My application directory looks like:

```plaintext
├── package.json
├── package-lock.json
├── src
│   └── Appointment.js
└── test
    └── Appointment.test.js
```

and the file contents are:

`package.json`:

```json
{
  "name": "appointments",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "Appointments project from Mastering React Test-Driven Development.",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "jest"
  },
  "repository": {
    "type": "git",
    "url": "example.com"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/plugin-transform-runtime": "^7.18.6",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.18.6",
    "@babel/preset-react": "^7.18.6",
    "jest": "^28.1.2",
    "jest-environment-jsdom": "^28.1.3"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@babel/runtime": "^7.18.6",
    "react": "^18.2.0",
    "react-dom": "^18.2.0"
  },
  "jest": {
    "testEnvironment": "jsdom"
  }
}
```

`src/Appointment.js`:

```js
import React from 'react';

export const Appointment = () => <div>Ashley</div>;
```

`test/Appointment.test.js`:

```js
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
// import {createRoot} from 'react-dom/client';

import {Appointment} from '../src/Appointment';

describe('Appointment', () => {
  it("renders the customer's first name.", () => {
    const customer = {firstName: 'Ashley'};
    const component = <Appointment customer={customer} />;
    const container = document.createElement('div');
    document.body.appendChild(container);

    ReactDOM.render(component, container);

    // const root = createRoot(container);
    // root.render(component);

    expect(document.body.textContent).toMatch('Ashley');
  });
});
```

With `ReactDOM.render()`, the test passes, but I get the following error:

```plaintext
  console.error
    Warning: ReactDOM.render is no longer supported in React 18. Use createRoot instead. Until you switch to the new API, your app will behave as if it's running React 17. Learn more: https://reactjs.org/link/switch-to-createroot

      11 |     document.body.appendChild(container);
      12 |
    > 13 |     ReactDOM.render(component, container);
         |              ^
      14 |
      15 |     expect(document.body.textContent).toMatch('Ashley');
      16 |   });

      at printWarning (node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:86:30)
      at error (node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:60:7)
      at Object.render (node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:29670:5)
      at Object.render (test/Appointment.test.js:13:14)
```

I looked up how to convert `ReactDOM.render()` to `createRoot()`, and changed the test to:

```js
import React from 'react';
// import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import {createRoot} from 'react-dom/client';

import {Appointment} from '../src/Appointment';

describe('Appointment', () => {
  it("renders the customer's first name.", () => {
    const customer = {firstName: 'Ashley'};
    const component = <Appointment customer={customer} />;
    const container = document.createElement('div');
    document.body.appendChild(container);

    // ReactDOM.render(component, container);

    const root = createRoot(container);
    root.render(component);

    expect(document.body.textContent).toMatch('Ashley');
  });
});
```

and the test fails as follows:

```plaintext
> appointments@1.0.0 test
> jest

 FAIL  test/Appointment.test.js
  Appointment
    ✕ renders the customer's first name. (9 ms)

  ● Appointment › renders the customer's first name.

    expect(received).toMatch(expected)

    Expected substring: "Ashley"
    Received string:    ""

      17 |     root.render(component);
      18 |
    > 19 |     expect(document.body.textContent).toMatch('Ashley');
         |                                       ^
      20 |   });
      21 | });
      22 |

      at Object.toMatch (test/Appointment.test.js:19:39)
      at TestScheduler.scheduleTests (node_modules/@jest/core/build/TestScheduler.js:317:13)
      at runJest (node_modules/@jest/core/build/runJest.js:407:19)
      at _run10000 (node_modules/@jest/core/build/cli/index.js:339:7)
      at runCLI (node_modules/@jest/core/build/cli/index.js:190:3)

Test Suites: 1 failed, 1 total
Tests:       1 failed, 1 total
Snapshots:   0 total
Time:        0.979 s, estimated 1 s
Ran all test suites.
```

How can I get this test to pass using `createRoot()`?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

After some more digging around, I've found that `act()` can be used in React 18 to force renders to occur before test asserts are checked. This allows for the tests to run immediately without waiting for Jest's done() to timeout when a test fails.

`globals.IS_REACT_ACT_ENVIRONMENT` must be set to `true` in the Jest configuration. Here I've updated `package.json`:

`package.json`:

```json
...
  "jest": {
    "testEnvironment": "jsdom",
    "globals": {
      "IS_REACT_ACT_ENVIRONMENT": true
    }
  }
...
```

The test can then be updated to use `act()` from `react-dom/test-utils`:

```js
import React from 'react';
import {createRoot} from 'react-dom/client';
import {act} from 'react-dom/test-utils';

import {Appointment} from '../src/Appointment';

describe('Appointment', () => {
  it("renders the customer's first name.", () => {
    const customer = {firstName: 'Ashley'};
    const component = <Appointment customer={customer} />;
    const container = document.createElement('div');
    document.body.appendChild(container);

    const root = createRoot(container);

    act(() => root.render(component));

    expect(document.body.textContent).toMatch('Ashley');
  });
});
```

Resources:

- The `act()` test utility docs: https://reactjs.org/docs/test-utils.html#act
- Setting up `act()` in React 18: https://reactjs.org/blog/2022/03/08/react-18-upgrade-guide.html#configuring-your-testing-environment

Answer (score 0):

React 17 looks to render immediately when you call `ReactDOM.render`:

```js
const App = () => {
    return 'foo';
};

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.querySelector('.react'));
console.log(document.querySelector('.react').textContent);
```

```html
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react@17/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@17/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>
<div class='react'></div>
```

In contrast, React 18 doesn't, it performs the render work only once any other code has finished (which will usually be a few milliseconds later):

```js
const App = () => {
    return 'foo';
};

ReactDOM.createRoot(document.querySelector('.react')).render(<App />);
console.log(document.querySelector('.react').textContent.trim());
```

```html
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react@18/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@18/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>
<div class='react'></div>
```

This difference is imperceptible to the eye, but will cause the test to fail because the rendering has not occurred by the time your `expect` runs.

One option is to [use the callback form of the test](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46077769) so that you can call `expect` after rendering has occurred.

```
it("renders the customer's first name.", (done) => {
    const component = <Appointment customer={ { firstName: 'Ashley' } } />;
    const container = document.body.appendChild(document.createElement('div'));
    createRoot(container).render(component);
    setTimeout(() => {
        expect(document.body.textContent).toMatch('Ashley');
        done();
    });
});
```

```js
const App = () => {
    return 'foo';
};

ReactDOM.createRoot(document.querySelector('.react')).render(<App />);
setTimeout(() => {
    console.log(document.querySelector('.react').textContent.trim());
});
```

```html
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react@18/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@18/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>
<div class='react'></div>
```